# PHP Find Last value in XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML file and I cannot figure out how I would get PHP to open this file and know that the last ID is 3.

```
<League>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>English Premier League</Name>
</League>
<League>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Name>English League Championship</Name>
</League>
<League>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Name>Scottish Premier League</Name>
</League>
```

Comment: You probably want to use SimpleXML which is included in PHP. Look at [the official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for more usage details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example using DOM and XPath:

```
<?php
$str = <<<XML
<root>
<League>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>English Premier League</Name>
</League>
<League>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Name>English League Championship</Name>
</League>
<League>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Name>Scottish Premier League</Name>
</League>
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query("(//Leagues/League)[last()]") as $league)
{
    echo $league->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

[**See a Live DEMO here!**](https://eval.in/33919)

[**More about XPath ?**](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

[**More about DOM ?**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with simplexml?

Comment: @Max yep there is but I am not a simplexml person, I prefer DOM since its commonly installed on most servers by default.

Comment: @Max: DOM and SimpleXML are close sisters in PHP. http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath